# Is this OOP convention true?

Tags: oop

Some time ago I've read something like a 'convention' for OOP, but I'm not sure if I remember it correctly.

It says that a method must take the most generic objects in inheritance hierarchy as parameters, while return the most descendant ones.

Is this true and if it is, can anybody explain a lil bit?

Example:

```
IList<T> someMethod(IList<T> someList)
{
    IList<T> resultList = new List<T>();

    ... do something with resultList ...

    return resultList;
}
```

According to the 'convention' the method above should return List, instead of IList?

Comment: I really doubt it. You'll always return *something* that fits your needs just fine. No more, no less.

Comment: If all the code which uses the method needs the instance as the specific subtype, you save the effort of having to cast it each time in the calling code.

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Having to cast from one type to another is in most cases a strong indicator of bad design anyways.

Answer (score 5):

It is often the case that a class declares a generic pointer to an object. Often the base class. At run time a more concrete class is injected through the constructor or a setter method which allows the code to be extended without being modified. This is a Holy Grail in software engineering. There is a rule that says that base classes should be substitutable by their derived classes - The Liskov substitution principle.
I am not sure about your example which does not seem to use the someList argument.

Comment: Agree with the Holy Grail

Answer (score 3):

Try reading about [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), specifically about [Covariance of return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

Following the above principles, you would return `IList` rather than `List`

> ...
>   Liskov's principle imposes some standard requirements on signatures
>   that have been adopted in newer object-oriented programming languages
>   (usually at the level of classes rather than types; see nominal vs.
>   structural subtyping for the distinction):
>
> - Contravariance of method arguments in the subtype.
> - Covariance of return types in the subtype.
> - No new exceptions should be thrown bymethods of the subtype, except where those exceptions are themselves
>     subtypes of exceptions thrown by the methods of the supertype.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to the Robustness principle, AKA the Postel's Law. You can google for it and find plenty of information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should generally return List, because List can then be implicitly cast to IList.

The convention is meant to simplify user code and make the methods as generic as possible.
If, in your example, you had used a `List<T>` argument, the method would have been hard to call, if the user was using a custom `IList` implementation, which is not `List`, even though it offers the same functionalities, and would actually make no difference to your method.

In the same way, if your method returned a `IList` rather than a `List`, any method which is defined in `List`, but not in `IList` wouldn't be accessible (unless you know that `IList` is actually a `List` and perform a cast). Though, this is a weaker rule than the previous one.

Consider the following case: you implement your method to return a `List`, but then you realize there is another class `OtherCollection : IList` that is more suited and offers better performance. Now, you have to modify the return type of your function, and the new version will be incompatible with the old one, because you changed the return type of a public method.

So, while this is almost always true for method arguments, it gets more complicated when it comes to return types.
When dealing with arguments, you should ask yourself:

1. Do I really need a so specific type?
2. How likely is it that I'm going to need such a specific type in the future?

When dealing with return types, on the other way:

1. Will the method user really need such a specific type?
2. Will the user need explicit casting to access the useful methods of my return value?
3. How likely is it that I'm going to need a more generic return type in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Never heard it that way before but it makes sense. Let's have a look at the parameter first.

If your method does something with an object given as parameter, it needs a certain set of oparations. If one type already has those operations, there is no need to go deeper in the type hierachy. This way your method can be used more flexible. If on the other hand your method does something that should only be done to a certain type, although a supertype already offers the needed operations, you should be more specific.

With the return type it is the other way around. If you have a specific type, why return it as one of it's supertypes? It would only limit the operations the client could call on the returned object. Even worse some developers might start to typecheck and cast to be able to do so.

While the other answers are mostly formally right (Liskov Substitution Principle) I thought I'd give a little more practical explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why return it as one of it's supertypes? So you can change the implementation and the callers won't notice. That is for proper encapsulation. And that principle has higher weight in OOP.